# How can I use WP_Site_Query to find a blog by blog name?

Tags: multisite, search

`WP_Site_Query` accepts a `search` argument but if a search term or phrase is supplied, only the `path` and `domain` columns can be searched.

The `site_search_columns` filter allows filtering of the columns to be searched but my understanding is blogname isn't a column in the database.

How can I use `WP_Site_Query` to find a blog by blog name?

Comment: Isn't the blogname stored in the options table of each blog ?

Comment: yes looks like it, so for 1000 blogs it would be stored in 1000 tables. Might e.g. need to collect it into a custom table and sync it on each blogname update, for large number of blogs.

Comment: for few blogs you could loop over `get_sites()` results and look into `switch_to_blog()`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @birgire. I'll try hooking to the blogname update and store a copy of it to make it easily searchable. I agree for a large network, the switch_to_blog() approach may not be feasible

Comment: @birgire would you suggest storing the copy in a custom table or site meta? I noticed WP_Site_Query supports `meta_query`

Comment: https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/01/28/multisite-support-for-site-metadata-in-5-1/

Comment: aha forgot about that blog_meta, never used it though, it's been few years since my last multisites adventure :-) Meta queries are meh but probably better than switch to blog. It looks like many plugins now a days prefer their own custom tables with db structure that suits them to speed up things with indexes etc. So use what ever suits your plugin / site (s)  and time table :-)

Comment: Thanks @birgire. It is a difficult decision because a custom table feels as though it'll provide superior performance yet wp_blogmeta feels as though it was created for this type of data. Decisions decisions :)

Comment: yes design decisions are hard :-) I think I would just start with the meta and then iterate on that and migrate into a custom table if it's getting slow :-)